# How to use Web App on smartphone to open prewritten email message and to open google maps

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I've created a jQuery Mobile web app and now I'm looking to add the following functionality. I have say the following email being displayed on the screen, user1@yahoo.com. When the user of a website clicks it will their native email app, say gamil, and have a configured message for them already to simply send to user1@yahoo.com

I'd like to do the same with an address, if the user of the web app clicks the address then it will open the users google maps.

I know this can be done because when I have a telephone number I can use the following:

`<a href="tel:0111590503">0111590503</a>` and it will open the dialing pad. I'm just not sure on how to do this with emails and locations using HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Emails

For emails you can simply use `mailto:the@ema.il` as per RFC2368. You can read the full spec over [here](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2368.txt).

> URLs for an ordinary individual mailing address:
>
> ```
>  <mailto:chris@example.com>
> ```
>
> A URL for a mail response system that requires the name of the file
>   in the subject:
>
> ```
>  <mailto:infobot@example.com?subject=current-issue>
> ```
>
> A mail response system that requires a "send" request in the body:
>
> ```
>  <mailto:infobot@example.com?body=send%20current-issue>
> ```
>
> A similar URL could have two lines with different "send" requests
>   (in    this case, "send current-issue" and, on the next line, "send
>   index".)
>
> ```
>  <mailto:infobot@example.com?body=send%20current-
>  issue%0D%0Asend%20index>
> ```
>
> An interesting use of your mailto URL is when browsing archives of 
>   messages. Each browsed message might contain a mailto URL like:
>
> ```
>  <mailto:foobar@example.com?In-Reply-
>  To=%3c3469A91.D10AF4C@example.com>
> ```
>
> A request to subscribe to a mailing list:
>
> ```
>  <mailto:majordomo@example.com?body=subscribe%20bamboo-l>
> ```
>
> A URL for a single user which includes a CC of another user:
>
> ```
>  <mailto:joe@example.com?cc=bob@example.com&body=hello>
> ```
>
> Another way of expressing the same thing:
>
> ```
>  <mailto:?to=joe@example.com&cc=bob@example.com&body=hello>
> ```

## Maps

For maps you will simply need to generate a link to Google maps, for which the Google maps app registers an intent on android, thus opening the native app rather than the browser if the user wishes to. To do this you can simply do:

> http://maps.google.com/?q=Bratislava,%20Slovakia